# Why is $\sum{(x_i-\overline{x})^2}$ = $\sum{(x_i-\overline{x})x_i}$ true?

Tags: mean, sum

I have seen this equality many times in books but I never found an explanatory derivation.

Comment: It has appeared a very great many times on this site.  The main difficulty is that it's almost impossible to search for the answers!

Comment: It is quite difficult to search equations in a text-match-based searcher

Comment: Agreed!  The duplicates I found are only the tip of the iceberg; I searched https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+orthogonal+residual.  Most of the demonstrations are absolutely identical to the answer you received (right down to the variable names), but the threads mention none of these terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum{(x_i-\overline{x})^2} = \sum{(x_i-\overline{x})x_i} - \sum{(x_i-\overline{x})\overline{x}} = \sum{(x_i-\overline{x})x_i} - \overline{x}\sum{x_i} + n\overline{x}^2 = \sum{(x_i-\overline{x})x_i} - \overline{x}n\overline{x} + n\overline{x}^2 = \sum{(x_i-\overline{x})x_i}$$

$\sum{x_i} = n\overline{x}$